# Eliminate variable on multiple equations

Tags: equation-solving, expression-manipulation, algebraic-manipulation, parametric-functions

I'm pretty new with Mathematica. I have to perform a really simple operation, but I'm really struggling with that.

I have a set of 4 equations, for example (they can also be more complex):

$ AA = 2 a + 4 b + 45 c + 5$

$ BB = 4 a + 45 b + 31 c + 78$

$ CC = 0.23 a + 0.4 b + 4.35 c + 0.12$

$ DD = 0.73 a + 0.2 b + 43.455 c + 3.12$

Now I would like to eliminate the $c$ variable from all the above equations, given the additional equation

$ c = 43.5 AA + 34 b + 32$

Ideally I should found $AA$, $BB$, $CC$ and $DD$ only function of $a$ and $b$.

Could you please tell me how to perform this simple operation? Could you also split the suggested code in 1) function definitions, 2) variable elimination. Working with a single long line it would be difficult for me.

Please ask additional question if I'm missing anything.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? Have you looked into e.g. the [documentation for `Solve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html?q=Solve) or at the ["Solving equations" tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SolvingEquations.html)?

Comment: What about `Eliminate`?http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/104946/5478

Comment: Enter "eliminate variable" (with or without quotes) into Help > Wolfram Documentation (really that should be done before rather than after posting).

Comment: Re your deleted answer. You need to `Flatten` the `List` of lists into a single `List`: `Eliminate[{eqnsMain, eqnsAdd} // Flatten, c]`

Answer (score 1):

```
eqns = {AA == 2 a + 4 b + 45 c + 5,
   BB == 4 a + 45 b + 31 c + 78,
   CC == 0.23 a + 0.4 b + 4.35 c + 0.12,
   DD == 0.73 a + 0.2 b + 43.455 c + 3.12};
```

Substituting for `c`

```
eqns2 = eqns /. c -> 43.5 AA + 34 b + 32

(*  {AA == 5 + 2 a + 4 b + 45 (32 + 43.5 AA + 34 b), 
 BB == 78 + 4 a + 45 b + 31 (32 + 43.5 AA + 34 b), 
 CC == 0.12 + 0.23 a + 0.4 b + 4.35 (32 + 43.5 AA + 34 b), 
 DD == 3.12 + 0.73 a + 0.2 b + 43.455 (32 + 43.5 AA + 34 b)}  *)
```

Since `AA` now appears in rhs of all equations, use [`Reduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce.html) to eliminate `AA` from rhs

```
List @@ Reduce[eqns2, {AA, BB, CC, DD}]

(*  {AA == -0.738564 - 0.00102223 a - 0.784053 b, 
 BB == 74.0468 + 2.62152 a + 41.7043 b, 
 CC == -0.434728 + 0.0365679 a - 0.0624585 b, 
 DD == -2.42154 - 1.20232 a - 4.4198 b}  *)
```

Or [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html)

```
Solve[eqns2, {AA, BB, CC, DD}][[1]] /. Rule -> Equal

(*  {AA == -0.738564 - 0.00102223 a - 0.784053 b, 
 BB == 74.0468 + 2.62152 a + 41.7043 b, 
 CC == -0.434728 + 0.0365679 a - 0.0624585 b, 
 DD == -2.42154 - 1.20232 a - 4.4198 b}  *)
```

EDIT: If you want to use [`Eliminate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Eliminate.html)

```
eqns3 = {
   AA == 2 a + 4 b + 45 c + 5,
   BB == 4 a + 45 b + 31 c + 78,
   CC == 0.23 a + 0.4 b + 4.35 c + 0.12,
   DD == 0.73 a + 0.2 b + 43.455 c + 3.12,
   c == 43.5 AA + 34 b + 32};

eqns4 = Eliminate[eqns3, c]

(*  a == 7.47796 + 18.6712 CC - 0.263852 DD && 
 AA == 1.27831 + 3.96322 CC + 0.121389 DD && 
 b == -2.58212 - 5.07913 CC - 0.154479 DD && 
 BB == -14.035 - 162.875 CC - 7.13412 DD  *)
```

Since the equations are not in the desired form, use `Solve` or `Reduce` to rearrange

```
Solve[eqns4, {AA, BB, CC, DD}][[1]] /. Rule -> Equal

(*  {AA == -0.738564 - 0.00102223 a - 0.784053 b, 
 BB == 74.0468 + 2.62152 a + 41.7043 b, 
 CC == -0.434728 + 0.0365679 a - 0.0624585 b, 
 DD == -2.42154 - 1.20232 a - 4.4198 b}  *)
```

Comment: That is working, thanks. However can I also use the command "Eliminate" to perform the same operation?